# Dynamics CRM 2013 hardware requirements

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware

What is the estimated hardware requirements for a Dynamics CRM Implementation that will be accessed by about 30 users with about 200K to 500K contact data? The implementation most likely will use Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Voting to close - server sizing questions are product recommendations, not ok per FAQ.

Comment: @TomTom This is a capacity planning question - we've got a family of canonical answers for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The system requirements documentation for CRM 2013 is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699831%28v=crm.6%29.aspx).

[The specific hardware requirements section is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699840%28v=crm.6%29.aspx), and I've pasted it out below.  Be aware that the requirements are just for the CRM server - if you install the SQL server on the same box, the minimum and recommended hardware requirements will be higher (though it's generally a better idea to have a dedicated SQL server running your SQL databases, and front end servers running whatever front end apps you have).

Your implementation sounds like a relatively small one, so you should be able to get away with the recommended minimums (not that you can really buy a server these days with 16 GB RAM, a 2Ghz quad-core and a 40 GB hard drive), but I wouldn't want to put myself in a position where I'm running my hardware close to its limits and don't have room to expand, and depending on concurrency and usage, you might find your hardware requirements for an acceptable user experience are much higher than the recommended minimums.

There's really no way to figure out what your user usage is going to be like until you have some usage data to work with, however, and "30 users" doesn't remotely begin to describe what kind of load they'll put on the server.  If you're using a VM, it makes that part of your job easy (just add more RAM and procs if needed), if you're using physical hardware, you just have to be sure to allow your self room to grow and expand your server if it turns out usage is heavier than anticipated.  (So, for example, put a decent processor in there instead of two cheap ones, and use higher capacity RAM DIMMs rather than packing the RAM slots with lower capacity DIMMs.)

---

### Processor

Minimum: x64 architecture or compatible dual-core 1.5 GHz processor

Recommended: Quad-core x64 architecture 2 GHz CPU or higher such as AMD Opteron or Intel Xeon systems

### Memory

Minimum: 2GB RAM

Recommended: 8GB RAM or more

### Hard disk

Minimum: 10 GB of available hard disk space

- Note:

  - Computers with more than 16GB of RAM will require more disk space for paging, hibernation, and dump files.

Recommended: 40 GB or more of available hard disk space

- Note:

  - Computers with more than 16GB of RAM will require more disk space for paging, hibernation, and dump files.

Comment: Note that it's pretty hard not to meet the *minimum* requirements here. I wouldn't consider deploying on anything less than the ***Recommended*** system (as a minimum) myself. "Minimum" means it runs. "Recommended" means you might actually be able to use it.